# Migration from eXist-db 1.4.x to 2.x

Tags: exist-db

We're going to migrate our application from eXist-db 1.4.1 to ~2.2 (probably RC2).
I`m wondering if anybody already did such a migration and what impediments they met?

I already found some documentation about this on official website and tried to Google, but didn't find much. For now I know that there were significant changes in the security model and some APIs are also changed. But still I want to know if somebody investigated further or maybe can share success story.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between 1.4.1 and 2.1/2.2 is that stored XQueries now need the executable flag to be set. You can fix your permissions automatically using a query as described in the [documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/upgrading.xml#D2.2.5).

It is also possible that some of your existing queries report errors on 2.1/2.2, which they did not before. In nearly all cases this happens because 1.4 was less strict about the XQuery specification and processed expressions which should not be allowed (the standard as well as the implementation evolved). Also, the query engine may now do additional checks to prevent potential issues. Usually the error messages by the compiler should directly lead to the code you have to fix. This may cost a few minutes, but it's worth the effort. Apart from this, no particular migration issues have been reported.